# What's the average temperature on the surface of ISS (International Space Station)

Tags: iss, temperature

The ISS is about 330-410 km above earth surface and within the thermosphere layer, in which according to Wikipedia the temperature can reach 1500 °C. However the gas inside this layer is highly diluted so it feels like 0 °C, which I find very confusing (what happens to the sun light that hits the object in that layer?!). So I'm wondering how much is the average temperature on the surface of ISS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the altitude of ISS, the temperature depends on whether it is measured in sunlight or otherwise. In sunlight, the temperature can reach 121$^{\circ}$C, while in darkness, it can plunge to -156$^{\circ}$C. [According to NASA](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast21mar_1/),

> Without thermal controls, the temperature of the orbiting Space Station's Sun-facing side would soar to 250 degrees F (121 C), while thermometers on the dark side would plunge to minus 250 degrees F (-157 C).